# Magento 2 pub/media broken symlink

Tags: magento2

I moved my Magneto2 v2.3.3 project to a new vps service. My operating system are Ubuntu 18.04.

When I'm doing `php bin/magneto setup:install` I get the following error:

> Missing write permissions to the following paths:
>     /var/www/stagedesign/html/root/pub/media

I checked if there where any broken symlinks using this command:

```
find -L . -type l
```

I looks to be a few hundred files that have broken symlinks under ./pub/media and ./pub/static

Should I import the files again?

I have tried these but with no success:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167881/is-it-safe-to-remove-all-broken-symlinks-in-entire-linux-system
- https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer/issues/153
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9111

Comment: Hi, You need to give 777 permission to your Media directory. for eg: 
sudo chmod 777 -r /directory_name

Comment: Hi! Tried that. I get the following error `Can't change the loose symlink`

Comment: please send your proper error so i find the solutions..

Comment: `chmod: can't change the loose symlink '/var/www/stagedesign/html/root/pub/media'`

Comment: Hello @NicklasGilbertsson  i think help this links 1> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/I-cannot-change-symbolic-link-permission/td-p/27731
2> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: Hi! I did both of them but I stil get the same problem. `In Installer.php line 905:
                                              
  Missing write permissions to the following paths:  
  /var/www/stagedesign/html/root/pub/media`